# LeaveOneOut to determine k of knn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, knn

I want to know the best k for k-nearest-neighbor. I am using LeaveOneOut to divide my data into train and test sets. In the code below I have 150 data entries, so I get 150 different train and test sets. K should be in-between 1 and 40.

I want to plot the cross-validation average classification error as a function of k, too see which k is the best for KNN.

Here is my code:

```
import scipy.io as sio
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut    
error = []
array = np.array(range(1,41))

dataset = pd.read_excel('Data/iris.xls')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values  
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values

loo = LeaveOneOut()
loo.get_n_splits(X)
for train_index, test_index in loo.split(X):
    #print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    #print(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)

    for i in range(1, 41):  
        classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)  
        classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
        error.append(np.mean(y_pred != y_test))

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))  
plt.plot(range(1, 41), error, color='red', linestyle='dashed', marker='o', markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=10)
plt.title('Error Rate K Value')  
plt.xlabel('K Value')  
plt.ylabel('Mean Error')
```

Comment: I figured out that when i put the second for loop i get an error array with 6000 entries. so i get every error for each fold. But idk how to fix it, that i get the mean error of this split.

Comment: Can you format your code correctly? I assume it's wrong because as it currently stands you'll only be running the classifier on the last `X_train`, `y_train` and so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating error at each prediction, thats why you have 6000 points in your `error` array. You need to collect the predictions of all points in the fold for a given `'n_neighbors'` and then calculate the error for that value.

You can do this:

```
# Loop over possible values of "n_neighbors"
for i in range(1, 41):  

    # Collect the actual and predicted values for all splits for a single "n_neighbors"
    actual = []
    predicted = []


    for train_index, test_index in loo.split(X):
        #print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

        classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)  
        classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

        # Append the single predictions and actual values here.
        actual.append(y_test[0])
        predicted.append(y_pred[0])

    # Outside the loop, calculate the error.
    error.append(np.mean(np.array(predicted) != np.array(actual)))
```

Rest of your code is okay.

There is a more compact way to do this if you use the [`cross_val_predict`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict

for i in range(1, 41):  

    classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)  
    y_pred = cross_val_predict(classifier, X, y, cv=loo)
    error.append(np.mean(y_pred != y))
```